# How to integrate jquery with php file

Tags: php, jquery

i'm new to PHP. I want to integrate the **CDN of jquery**.
I allready integrated files to my index. php:

```
<script src="<?php echo $this->baseurl ?>/templates/<?php echo $this->template;?>/js/cc_jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

How to implement the link file instead of the file path?
I'd be most appreciative! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include it directly with the `CDN` url.

```
<script src="http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

or, to include it from the php you can do something like this:

```
echo "<script src='http://codeorigin.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js'></script>";
```

CDN for jQuery: http://codeorigin.jquery.com/